# Flutter - Filtering lists for use with ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, e-commerce

I'm trying to put what I've learned in Udemy courses on Flutter to good use by building an app for a simple, fake shoe store. The main feature I'd like to have in the main page of the app is a horizontal ListView (as such, a scrollable widget) with so-called 'Hot Offers.' All products in the store are implemented with a *Shoe* model class which includes parameters such as name, brand, an image path, and most importantly, a boolean `isSpecialSale` that designates whether the shoe is (what else?) on special sale and hence should be put in the Hot Offers section. However, I don't know for certain how to filter the list of shoes, `shoeListFull`, into a list of `onSpecialSale == True` shoes and deploy it to the abovementioned ListView.

I have a simple stateless widget in which I've tried to create the Hot Offers list, here named `shoesFiltered`, but this returns nothing when I instantiate it in the main page with `shoeList` set to `shoeListFull` (as mentioned, the list that contains every shoe on sale). Am I missing something? Please note that I haven't yet gotten to the part of the my course where stateful widgets are introduced, so I'm trying to work without having to use setState or the like.

```
class ShoeTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShoeTile({super.key, required this.title, required this.shoeList});

  final String title;
  final List<Shoe> shoeList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    

    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          for (Shoe shoe in shoeList) {
            List<Shoe> shoesFiltered = [];
            if (shoe.isSpecialSale) {
              shoesFiltered.add(shoe);
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your current code is just looping and adding items to filtered list. To display something, you need to return a widget:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (shoe.isSpecialSale) {
            return YourCustomWidgetToDisplaySale();
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to return a widget inside `itemBuilder` to see the result.
If you're using an existing List you should not filter them inside itemBuilder but before `ListView` itself. Easiest way would be:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final filtered = shoeList.where((e) => e.isSpecial).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: filtered.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(title: Text(filtered[i].name)));
  }
```